# Can I use an email address as a discount code in Expresso Store?

Tags: ecommerce, expresso-store, expresso

I'm considering purchasing [Store by Exp:resso](https://exp-resso.com/store) in order to use the discount feature for client project.

I'm wondering if the discount value can have the characters normally used in an email address. Can a discount code be equal to test@email.com or is it randomly generated by software?

Comment: My bad, Crescendo is Exp:resso. Two branches of same organization. I'm still not certain about the discount value being an email address. Would that be like a promo code for discounts?

Comment: I've heavily edit the title and question to more clearly state the question.

Comment: Was your question answered below? If yes, please select the correct answer by checking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Promo codes in Store by Exp:resso are set manually by you. I've tested that you can indeed use an email address as a code. Screenshot below.

http://cl.ly/image/0q070i1f2o0y

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a problem entering an email address as a promo code but you might need to increase the database column length. Currently it is set to 20 characters which might not be long enough to be reliable for email address (mine for example would exceed the character limit). You can see the documentation for creating PromoCodes [here](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/settings/promo_codes.html).